# Specify perl script to run on an earlier version of perl

Tags: perl

I have some old production computer which has Perl 5.0 (updated version 1998).
I developed a script on my office computer with Activestate Perl 5.24.1

When i tried to run on the older version (installed on Windows XP) it drops several warnings, etc can not know about `USE Warnings;`, or `three parameter open` function.

The our keyword cannot be used with `use strict;`

```
our %Config = (
        'SourcePath' => "",
        'TargetPath' => "",
        'Station'    => "",
        'Product'    => "",
        'LogLevel'   => 0
    );
```

When i tried to print a string with a hash variable in, it drops a warning too.
The code is:

```
print $fhw qq/  <FACTORY NAME="FLEX_ZALA" TESTER="$Config{'Station'}" FIXTURE="" USER="" LINE="" SHIFT="" \/>\n/;
```

The Station variable is not known for it.

I cannot develop on a production machine, but cannot install this old version on my office computer too.

How can i force to run my script with perl 5.24.1 in compatibily mode 5.0?

I using a windows 7 X64 PC for office.

Thanks.

UPD1:
The XP Perl version is:

> Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600] (C) Copyright 1985-2001
>   Microsoft Corp.
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\grprog1>perl -v
>
> This is perl, version 5.003_07
>
> Copyright 1987-1996, Larry Wall
>
> ```
>     + suidperl security patch
>     Win32 port Copyright (c) 1995-1996 Microsoft Corporation.
>             All rights reserved.
>     Developed by ActiveWare Internet Corp., http://www.ActiveWare.com
> ```
>
> Perl for Win32 Build 316 - Built 09:44:44 Mar 13 1998
>
> Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License
>   or the GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5.0
>   source kit.

UPD2:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\grprog1>perl -V Summary of my perl5 (patchlevel 1) configuration:   Platform:
    osname=MSWin32, osver=3.51, archname=i386-win32
    uname=''
    hint=recommended   Compiler:
    cc='cl', optimize=''
    cppflags=''
    ccflags =''
    ldflags =''
    stdchar='char', d_stdstdio=, usevfork=false
    voidflags=15, castflags=0, d_casti32=, d_castneg=
    intsize=4, alignbytes=4, usemymalloc=n, randbits=15   Libraries:
    so=dll
    libpth=
    libs=
    libc=   Dynamic Linking:
    dlsrc=dl_win32.xs, dlext=pll, d_dlsymun=
    cccdlflags='', ccdlflags='', lddlflags=''


Characteristics of this binary (from libperl):   Built under MSWin32   Compiled at Mar 13 1998 09:44:44   @INC:
    C:\Teradyne\GRNavigate\228x\lib\perl
    ..\lib\i386-win32
    ..\lib
    .
```

Comment: You will need to find an older binary. You cannot tell Perl to emulate an older version. Please run `perl -V` on the old machine and tell us exactly what version you have there. Is that an ActivePerl too, or is it something you compiled manually? Both ActivePerl as well as Strawberry only list Perls down to 5.8 for download (though for ActivePerl you need to have a commercial licence to get old ones).

Comment: In 1998 Perl 5.4 was current. You have to go back to 1994 for the release of v5.0. Do you really need to run a 23-year-old image?

Comment: Thanks. I asked for `perl -V` with a capital `V` though, which displays even more information. But this is already useful information.

Comment: Added perl version to comment. Yes, i need to use this version, because almost 15 tester has this version, and it is an ICT tester part. I can not tell what will happening if i update the perl version.

Comment: [Here's a brief history](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=888967) of the Windows Perl world. ActiveWare became ActiveState. I think getting that exact version is going to be pretty hard.

Comment: https://www.cpan.org/ports/win32/Standard/x86/ has some old versions. I cannot see a 5.003 though. But there is something 5.004 and newer. Might be worth a try. I also found http://www.lib.ru/PERL/Perl_for_Win32_FAQ_1.txt_with-big-pictures.html, which lists a few things, including how to build your own. In that case, all you need is the source code and build tools.

Comment: Thanks for the old installers, i will search a computer which has not have a perl installation yet. i cannot install the office computer because it already has a never version what is using an another test development software...

Comment: This seems to be exactly the sort of thing that virtual machines are designed to handle.

Comment: I will try to make an exe with PAR-Packer from the source, and try to use it on the testers, so it will not depends on the onsite version. I will feedback if it is working. Just a flag: Do not run pp with flag -x if you have return code different from 0in your code, because it will run your script, and you will get SYSTEM ERROR!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you have Computer A which has `perl` `5.003_7`. Therefore, copying that distribution from Computer A to Computer B where you want to do development is the most straightforward answer.

You say the testers also have this version of Perl. Therefore, your company must have bought either a site license or some specific number of licenses from ActiveState. You should investigate that first.

If you are stuck, contact ActiveState for support. They may provide you one for a fee.

Your company, however, faces the problem of having operations depend on ancient, no longer supported software to run programs which probably have problems of their own. It would be a good idea to move into this century.

Comment: Unfortunatelly these testers coming from other sites, and working for over years. Because of they are a lot of cheaper than a fresh new updated system. We havent any licenses for it. We cannot change the operating system, PC or test software, because we havent any installer, license for update these...

Comment: You do not need an installer and you know where to got for licenses.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must, no way around it, run ancient perl, your scripts cannot use more modern stuff.

Check out perlbrew to have more than one version of perl on your development/test box so you can test your code on several versions of perl with one command.

And perhaps also http://perldoc.perl.org/perl.html to see the docs of older perls.
 It goes back only to 5.8.8 (~2005), but better than using docs for 5.24 in your situation.